# Ruby on Rails Collect Returns enclosed array (variable:undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arraycollection

I had a controller that was returning all the articles of my website

```
 @articles = Article.find(all)
```

and a partial that used to render the @articles array.

I have changed my controller to :

```
@articles = User.find(1).topics.map { |t| t.articles }
```

So I can return some other data as well

After inspection on the Rails Console I found out that the problem is that the output array of collect does not match the Article.find(all)

Output array of find(all)

```
[#<Article id: 1, user_id: 2, title: "test">]
```

Output array of collect

```
[[#<Article id: 1, user_id: 2, title: "test">]]
```

When I'm trying to render the parcial i get:

```
variable:undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class
```

My Index

```
<%= render :partial => @articles%>
```

and then the parcial:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current h(article.title), article %> <%= h(article.body) %>
```

Does anyone knows how to overcome the problem with the double brackets [[ ]] of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the first line, I think you have a typo that should be `:all` instead of `all` :D

`t.articles` returns you a collection of articles.

So `map {|t| t.articles}` gives you a collection of collections of articles (the array of arrays).

You could try this:

```
@articles = User.find(1).topics.map { |t| t.articles }.flatten.uniq
# uniq if an article could belongs to two or more topics. Otherwise it is not needed.
```

Comment: `:all` instead of `all`...any problems..?